# jTemplate Foreach does not render single row

Tags: jquery, jtemplates

I'm using the standard Main/Row jTemplate pattern but for some reason the foreach only works when there's more than one row (of StatusDetail). If it's a single row of data it doesn't render (the row inside the foreach that is. The part of the table before that does still render).

```
Data:
{
    "MG": {
        "Status": "In Transit",
        "StatusDetail": {
            "StatusCode": "Actual Pickup",
            "Date": {
                "@type": "actual",
                "#text": "11/13/2012 09:00"
                },
            "Location": "Mentor, OH "
        }
    }
}
```

jTemplate code:

```
{#template MAIN}
<table id="results_hdr" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
        <td class="FieldLabels">Status</td>
        <td>{$T.MG.Status}</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="FieldLabels">Name</td>
        <td>{$T.MG.Name}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr><td colspan="6" style="background-color:White;"></td></tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Date</td>
        <td colspan="3">Detail</td>
        <td colspan="2">Location</td>
    </tr>
    {#foreach $T.MG.StatusDetail as SD}
        {#include ROW root=$T.SD}
    {#/for}
</table>
<br />
{#/template MAIN}
{#template ROW}
    <tr>
        <td>
            {$T.Date["#text"]}</td>
        <td colspan="3">
            {$T.StatusCode}</td>
        <td colspan="2">
            {$T.Location}</td>
    </tr>
{#/template ROW}
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to iterate through `$T.MG.StatusDetail` but it's not an array, so the `{#foreach $T.MG.StatusDetail as SD}` statement is not doing what you expect.

Change your data to the following so that `MG.StatusDetail` is actually an array and it will work:

Data:

```
var data = {
    "MG": {
        "Status": "In Transit",
        "StatusDetail": [
            {
                "StatusCode": "Actual Pickup",
                "Date": {
                    "type": "actual",
                    "text": "11/13/2012 09:00"
                },
                "Location": "Mentor, OH "
            }
        ]
    }
};
```

Here's a [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/axGcs/1/).

Comment: Thanks, that was it. My XSL that was working on the source XML was off.